# Reading text file and removing specific characters

Tags: java

After someone inputs a text file, I have to make it so it will read the text file that the user inputted.

Using a switch statement, how do I make sure the first word and last word doesn't have a specific character?

The first word should not have a single-quotation mark, double-quotation mark, a dollar sign, or a period.

The last word should not have a single-quotation mark, double-quotation mark, semi-colon, colon, period, comma, hyphen, exclamation point, or question mark remove it.

I am using hasNext in my while so that it prints each word on one line.

Comment: Show us your code. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: exactly jesper, I don't want to show my code so nobody can do my homework for me.

Comment: Hi Maerics, I have the code generating the text file. I've tried switch statements but I'm just confused on how someone can input the text file name, edit the text file, and print it. How is it that java can edit a text file that was inputted by a user?

Comment: You can read in the text file using bufferedreader / filereader then edit / process it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you read in your first word you can call this function (passing in the first word as your parameter), it will return true if the word contains any illegal characters. You could then easily create another one to test your last word against.

```
public boolean containsIllegalChar(String testWord){
boolean containsIllegalChar = false;

for(int count=0; count < testWord.length(); count++){
     char testChar = testWord.charAt(count);
     switch (testChar)
     {
     case ''': containsIllegalChar = true;
     break;
     case '"': containsIllegalChar = true;
     break;
     case '$': containsIllegalChar = true;
     break;
     case ' ': containsIllegalChar = true;
     break;
     default: break;
     }
}
return containsIllegalChar;
}
```

To test the last word you could use this structure

```
String lastWord = "";
while((holder = reader.read()) != -1){  
     lastWord = holder;
     //YOUR PROCESSING
}
boolean testLastWord = containsIllegalCharLastWord(lastWord);

if(testLastWord){
//Contains illegal char
}
else{
//Does not contain
}
```

You could also replace containsIllegalChar function by testing your string against a nice regex. E.g

```
boolean validWord = ("piz'za".matches("[^'\"$ ]+")) ? true : false;
System.out.println(validWord);
```

Result:

> false

Hope this helps.
Phil

Comment: Thank you PhilNerd. How would you incorporate something that should be deleted from a statement? say, "Hello, World" then using the switch statement to produce "Hello World" (deleting the comma)

Comment: You could set the method to return an int. Set the int to -1 before the switch, if the word contains an illegal char - change the int to the position of the char. Once the char is returned - check its value (-1 = no illegal characters, 0+ = illegal). Then String word = word.replace(word.charAt(positionReturned), "");

Comment: for the switch statement, how were you able to use a string instead of an int for the case's?

Comment: I used a char - char testChar = testWord.charAt(count);

Comment: Don't forget to thank me by selecting the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Well you can easily do this by using `Character` class method `isLetterOrDigit(char ch)`.

Comment: Hi Kumar, is this class method replacing a character?

Comment: @Leroy this isLetterOrDigit(char ch) method of Character class gives you the capability to identify that the character is a special symbol... so once you get hold of this you can then check is it the one you want to be in the first and the last word..and then you can do as you wish to...